# Why do my pagination displays the max number of pages when it's supposed to display only 1 or 2 pages?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Search.php

Why do my pagination display the max number of pages when my query searched 7 results that only needs to display 1 page

```
                <?php // $s=$ _GET[ 's']; $catnum=$ _GET[ 'catnum']; $type=$ _GET[ 'type']; $low=$ _GET[ 'low']; $high=$ _GET[ 'high']; $unit_size_x=$ _GET[ 'unit_size_x']; $unit_size_y=$ _GET[ 'unit_size_y']; $post_tag=$ _GET[ 'post_tag']; // if($catnum){ // $taxquerysp[]=a rray( // 'taxonomy'=>'property_categories', // 'include_children'=>false, // 'field'=>'term_id', // 'operator'=>'AND' // ); // } // if($post_tag){ // $taxquerysp[] = array( // 'taxonomy'=>'property_categories', // 'include_children'=>false, // 'field'=>'slug', // 'operator'=>'AND' // ); // } // if($type){ // $metaquerysp[] = array( // 'key'=>'type', // 'value'=> $type, // 'compare'=>'=', // ); // } $metaquerysp[] = array( 'key'=>'monthly_rent', 'value'=>array( $low, $high ), 'compare'=>'BETWEEN', 'type'=>'NUMERIC', ); $metaquerysp[] = array( 'key'=>'unit_size', 'value'=>array( $unit_size_x, $unit_size_y ), 'compare'=>'BETWEEN', 'type'=>'NUMERIC', ); $metaquerysp['relation'] = 'AND'; ?>


                <?php $paged=g et_query_var( 'paged') ? get_query_var( 'paged') : 1; $args=a rray( 'post_type'=> 'property', 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'orderby' => 'DATE', 'paged' => $paged, // 's' =>$s // 'tax_query' => $taxquerysp, 'meta_query' => $metaquerysp ); ?>
                <?php $query=n ew WP_Query( $args ); ?>


                <div class="mtb30" style=" display: block;">
                    <?php if($query -> have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php while($query -> have_posts()): $query->the_post();?>

                            <p>
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>


                <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>

            </div>
        </div>

    <?php if (function_exists( "pagination")) { pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages); } ?>
```

Here is the url of my work [link](http://c-net-ph.com/property/?s=&catnum=condominium&unit_size_x=40&unit_size_y=50&low=0&high=9999999)

Comment: Paste all relevant code into your question as text, _not_ as an image.

Comment: sorry i'm new here, i already edited it thanks.

Comment: You're defining and using `$query` but you are sending `$wp_query->max_num_pages` to the pagination. Shouldn't you send `$query->max_num_pages`?

Comment: That solved the problem, how did i missed that. Thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I've written it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the filtered results in the variable `$query`, but later, for your pagination, you're using `$wp_query` instead.

It should work if you change:

```
pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages);
```

to

```
pagination($query->max_num_pages);
```

That should give you the `max_num_pages` for the query you actually made.